# Rails – saving existing record id instead of duplicating record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-6

I am learning Rails at the moment, I'm a total novice. I'm hoping to be able to get help from the Rails experts here. I've tried to search through StackOverflow but haven't been able to find a solution.

So there are a `Pet` model that has `Breed` model for its references which references to `Category` model, So the 3 models:

```rb
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :breed
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :breed
  has_one :category, through: :breed

class Breed < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :pets, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :breeds, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pets, through: :breed
```

I have already set up the form using `simple_form`. When a new Pet is created, the user is able to `select` the existing `Category` options that is associated with `Breed`. Then in the form, a `breed.name` attribute is set as a `text_field` that user can input their own. Please below the nested attribute part:

```html
...
<!-- Nested Breed & Category Attributes -->
<%= f.simple_fields_for :breed, Breed.new do |breed| %>
  <%= breed.error_notification %>
  <%= breed.error_notification message: breed.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if breed.object.errors[:base].present? %>
  <div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <%= breed.association :category, collection: Category.order(:id),
                                       label: "Animal Category", required: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
      <%= breed.input :name, required: true,
                             label: "Breed", placeholder: "Domestic short hair",
                             hint: "Type 'unknown', if unsure", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So my question is, how can I save the new pet with an existing `breed_id` record without duplicating it with a different `breed_id`?

So at the moment, I already have an existing record of `breed_id : 1`, that consists of `category_id: 1 (for Cat), and name: 'domestic short hair'` – if I create a new pet with these same values in the form, it will duplicate the record, it's supposed to save `breed_id: 1`, but instead, the new pet is saved under `breed_id: 15` ...

When I check on the `console`:

```rb
irb(main):001:0> Breed.find_by_name("domestic short hair")
  Breed Load (6.8ms)  SELECT "breeds".* FROM "breeds" WHERE "breeds"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "domestic short hair"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Breed id: 1, name: "domestic short hair", category_id: 1, created_at: "2021-08-14 13:12:41.266154000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-08-14 13:12:41.266154000 +0000">
irb(main):002:0> Breed.last
  Breed Load (8.2ms)  SELECT "breeds".* FROM "breeds" ORDER BY "breeds"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Breed id: 15, name: "domestic short hair", category_id: 1, created_at: "2021-08-16 04:08:31.602249000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-08-16 04:08:31.602249000 +0000">
```

What's the best way to update my `controller / model / form helper` (I'm not sure which one), so it prevents the duplicating? I currently don't have a `breeds_controller`, and only using the `pets_controller`, which is a basic one from Scaffolding:

```rb
pets_controller.rb

  def show
  end

  # GET /pets/new
  def new
    @pet = Pet.new
    @pet.build_breed
  end
  
  # GET /pets/1/edit
  def edit
  end
  
  # POST /pets or /pets.json
  def create
    @pet = current_user.pets.new(pet_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pet.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pet, notice: "Pet was successfully added." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pet }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @pet.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

...

  private

  def pet_params
   params.require(:pet).permit(:owner_id, :name, :dob, :gender, :bio, :instagram,
                                breed_attributes: [:name, :category_id])
  end
```

I've tried to write a `before_save :existing_breed_record` in the model `breed.db`, which I think is wrong...

```rb
class Breed < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :pets, dependent: :destroy 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category
  before_save :existing_breed_record

  private

    def existing_breed_record
     if self.find_by(category_id, name).exists?
      return self.id
    end
end
```

Here is my `schema.db`

```rb
  create_table "breeds", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "category_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_breeds_on_category_id"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "pets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "owner_id", null: false
    t.bigint "breed_id", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.date "dob"
    t.integer "gender"
    t.string "bio"
    t.string "instagram"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["breed_id"], name: "index_pets_on_breed_id"
    t.index ["owner_id"], name: "index_pets_on_owner_id"
  end
```

I read from the guides that there is `find_or_create_by` method that I think is what I need, but I'm not sure where and how to implement it...

For database and Rails experts, for the sake of learning, how would you suggest I do this better next time? Should I have the `breed` as a string attribute/column to the Pet model and directly associate the `Category` model to Pet instead?

Comment: Did you already try using the `first_or_initialize` method? Sounds like a good fit.

Comment: Thank you for responding @SebastianPlasschaert I haven't and not sure about the method, how do I implement it?

Comment: Opinion: `accepts_nested_attributes_for` isn't really the best solution for all use cases and if you're doing multiple levels or need a lot of logic a better alternative is most likely to create separate controllers for breeds and categories and use AJAX to create the nested records on the fly. This lets you apply seperate access control as you might not trust all users to create breeds or categories and it lets you have a far better user experience. For example you can use an autocomplete to lookup the breed as the user is typing which is a lot more helpful and will avoid duplicate data.

Comment: However it is a fairly advanced topic and you might want to sidestep this feature until you have a bit more rails experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice Max, that is what I wanted, but yes I'm not up to that yet for this project I'm doing. I was actually thinking to discard the `breed model` and just use the `category` as a general animal type without adding too much details for now...

Comment: I would lose the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for `Breed` (as Max already suggested) and use a `first_or_initialize` in the create action. I'll try to set up an answer for you in the following hour.

Comment: Much appreciated Sebastian!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my teacher, we finally found a solution. It's a bit messy, but it no longer duplicates any existing record!

First of, thanks to @Yunwei.W, as suggested, I added `@pet.breed` in my nested form (was previously `:breed, Pet.new do ...`:

```html
...
<!-- Nested Breed & Category Attributes -->
<%= f.simple_fields_for :breed, @pet.breed do |breed| %>
...
```

Then in the `pets_controller.rb`:

```rb
def create
 # Preventing duplicates when breed name mathes exsiting record
 breed = Breed.find_by_name(params[:pet][:breed_attributes][:name]) || Breed.create(name: params[:pet][:breed_attributes][:name], category_id: params[:pet][:breed_attributes][:category_id])

 @pet = current_user.pets.new(pet_params.except(params[:pet][:breed_attributes][:name]))

 @pet.breed = breed

...

end
```

There is definitely a better solution than this, but I'm so glad it finally works after having this blocker for 3 days. Thank you everyone who has contributed to help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to use the nested form, you could add the `before_save` method to `Pet`

```rb
\\pet.rb

before_save :check_existing_breed


def check_existing_breed
  if self.breed&.name and breed = Breed.find_by(name: self.breed&.name)
    self.breed = breed
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I've tried changing the `<%= f.simple_fields_for :breed, Breed.new do |breed| %>` to `<%= f.simple_fields_for @pet.breed do |breed| %>` 

But this error occurs:
on the server terminal: "UNPERMITTED PARAMETER: :breed" and on the view 
<%= f.simple_fields_for @pet.breed do |breed| %> was highlighted, and `NoMethodError in Pets#create`, `undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass`

Does it mean I need to add something on my Pet#create controller? And what would that be?

Comment: @a-sh. try `<%= f.simple_fields_for :breed, @pet.breed do |breed| %>` instead.

Comment: Yes I did try that, but unfortunately, it still duplicates the record, but no more error :-(

Comment: ok, did you try `<%= f.simple_fields_for :breed do |breed| %>` @a-sh.

Comment: ok i see what's going on here, you are trying to create a new `Pet` with existing `Breed`. in this case, when you initialise your `@pet` do `@pet.breed = existing_breed` in your controller. ( i thought you were updating an existing pet)

Comment: Yes, I've tried `:breed` only without instantiating `Breed.new do`, the breed text field disappears from the form view.

It's more about if users's breed param matches existing record, I want it to use that breed id instead of duplicating the existing record (with the same values, but different id)

Comment: Thanks @Yunwei.W! Sorry for this silly question, do I need to edit anything on the pet#create controller for this to work though?

Comment: No, what is does is when you save a pet, it will check if db has a bread with the same name, if there is one, it will set the `self.breed` to the `breed` it found. otherwise it will keep on creating a new one with your form data. Give it a go though. i didn't test the code.